# javascript array logic not rendering properly in react with map component

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, use-effect

This is a pretty interesting issue I'm facing. So basically I have two files:

When dtmf is 1, found should return true and the rest of the code should run smoothly. But for some reason, found returns false which ruins the rest of the code. I tested the logic in a separate js compiler with the values in the screenshot below and the logic worked fine.

Not sure why React is behaving this way. It seems as if the variables are not being rendered properly. Maybe need to wait for them to be fully initialized or something?

Let me know. Been working at this for a while and got nowhere. Any help would be very appreciated.
[Console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHL0v.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're comparing two different types:

- Your `dmtfs` is an array of `{ value: string; label string }` objects. Even though the strings represent numbers, they're still strings.
- Your ìvr_dests`uses actual numbers for the`dtmf` field.

Therefore, you're comparing `'1' === 1` which returns false due to being different types.

Comment: thanks for the response. I changed the code to dtmf_val.toString() and it still produced same results

Comment: `dtmf_val` already was the string. The values in `ivr_dests` are numbers. Add some extra log statements (or breakpoints) and you should see the difference.